# Problem with Array following curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier

I want to add this edge on shoe which should follow line. I made curve which should represent where it should go. I modeled that edge with stitches on it, but can't get it right. First it is rotated wrong, then it doesn't start on beggining of curve, it starts somewhere in middle and so on. Is it about some loc,roc,scale values, or is it about where origin is set or anything like that?[image]
[image]

Comment: Apart from @vklidu's answer, without looking at the file I can tell that for using the curve modifier usually it is important how the mesh is rotated (the mesh, not the object) and where the origin is etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use Subdivision modifier, rather go to *Curve > Set Spline Type >* **Nurbs**

Also move vertices to origin center to let snitching follow the curve.

[image]

[image]

Origins of all participated object has to be on the same place.

[image]

Comment: It's better, but still not exactly as I want. Curve is on shoe, but those stitches are above.